# Using Database with Pyside and Socket

Tags: python, database, sockets, pyside, qtsql

I am working on my Python project using PySide as my Ui language. My projet is a game which require an internet connection to update the users'score and store in the database.

My problem is how can I store my database in the internet. I mean that all users can access this information when they are connected to an internet (when they are playing my game) and the information/database must be updated all the time.

I am not sure which database is the most appropriate, how to store this information/database in the internet, how to access this information.

I am using Python and PySide.
For the database, I currently use PySide.QtSql .

Thank you for answer(s) or suggestion(s).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PySide .. but the idea is

you need to build a function that when internet connection is available it should synchronize your local database with online database and in the server-side you need to build a script that can handle requests ( POST / GET ) to receive the scores and send it to database and I suggest MySQL ..

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Is it mean that the server-side must be online all the time? @mustafa96m

Comment: Yes it must be .. you gonna build it on server in case you publish it on global scale .. QtSQL im not that familiar with it but I think it is an offline database like sqlite .. there is a lot of MySQL-Client Frameworks like MySQLdb . but it's not recommended to use for direct connection I mean like this will put you under many security issues .. so there is an alternative way to use mysql in way which is much secure by building a server-side script as Data Handler and each time you want to update a score you send from your local application as a HTTP Request (GET/POST) to the server script

Comment: It seems confusing because I am not familiar with the internet connection in Python. Thank you for your answer. I hope that I can understand this soon. :)